# Not able to pip install web3 on my VS Code terminal due to Visual C++ error

Tags: visual-studio-code, web3py

I'm trying to install web3py via pip in Visual Studio Code but I am getting an error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

[image: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.]

I tried installing build tools for Visual Studio app, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the required Microsoft build tools from here:

   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. Open the download and select

   `Workloads > C++ build tools`
3. Install the selected C++ build tools.